# UIButton custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Hello I have the following code and one custom `UIButton` class I created.

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1];
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

How can i use this code in my custom `UIButton` class and use this code throughout all my buttons instead of duplicating this code for every single `UIButton` I create in my project.

Comment: use your custom UIButton subclass instead of UIButton.

Comment: you can inherit a class of UIButton and in that you can these lines to that class and in that instead of mybutton you can use self.backgroundcolor and add that class to button in storyboard

Comment: just paste this code in your custom UIButton class and inherit your custom class for all UIButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here check these images it might help you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom class inherit `UIButton` class. On this class you can custom your property like you did, and use this class for everywhere you want.

```
@interface YourButton : UIButton
```

Comment: i dont really understand i am new to objective c

Answer (score 0):

You can create Category of UIButton in Objective C.

```
@interface UIButton ( ExtendButton )

+(UIButton *) myButton;

@end

@implementation UIButton

+(UIButton *) myButton {

UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
theButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1];
theButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
return theButton;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new NSObjectClass for name custombuttonClass

custombuttonClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface custombuttonClass : NSObject

+(void)custombutton : (UIButton *)btn;

@end
```

custombuttonClass.m

```
#import "custombuttonClass.h"

@implementation custombuttonClass

+(void)custombutton : (UIButton *)btn
{
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1];
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    btn.clipsToBounds=YES;
}

@end
```

import custombuttonClass where to you use and call this method
Example :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "custombuttonClass.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [custombuttonClass custombutton:myButton]; // add your button as a parameter

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```